# convert into number of years based on experience in string using python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column with data like
9 years 3 months 22 days. How to convert it into
=9+(3/12)+(22/365)
=9.31

I want output as 9.31.

How to do the same in python? Please anyone can help me out?

Comment: What about leap years?  How many days are actually in a year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If leaps years are not important extract values by [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and count new column by multiple with dictionary and sum values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['9 years 3 months 22 days',
                           '3 YEARS 6 MONTHS', 
                           '4 YEARS', 
                           '3 YEARS',
                            '3.6']})

numeric = pd.to_numeric(df['col'], errors='coerce')
print (numeric)
y = df['col'].str.extract(r'(?i)(\d+)\s*year', expand=False).astype(float)
m = df['col'].str.extract(r'(?i)(\d+)\s*month', expand=False).astype(float).div(12)
d = df['col'].str.extract(r'(?i)(\d+)\s*day', expand=False).astype(float).div(365)

df['float'] = y.add(m, fill_value=0).add(d, fill_value=0).fillna(numeric)
print (df)
                        col     float
0  9 years 3 months 22 days  9.310274
1          3 YEARS 6 MONTHS  3.500000
2                   4 YEARS  4.000000
3                   3 YEARS  3.000000
4                       3.6  3.600000
```

Comment: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer. How to overcome this error. I need to apply where the column has string only?

Comment: @Mallesh - Can you try `df['col'].str.extract('(\d+)\s*years\s*(\d+)\s*months\s*(\d+)\s*days').astype(int)` change to `df['col'].str.extract('(\d+)\s*years\s*(\d+)\s*months\s*(\d+)\s*days').astype(float)` ?

Comment: @Mallesh - Working now?

Comment: @Mallesh - added more general solution.

Comment: 9 years 3 months 22 days
3 YEARS
6 MONTHS
3.6
4 YEARS
3 YEARS


The output which i want is (in years)
9.31
3
0.5
3.6
4
3

Comment: @Mallesh - seems second solution should working.

Comment: Ok i will try with second solution.

Comment: Everything working fine but if some float number is there 4.3, it is converting into zero. but i want it as 4.3 only. Thanks

Comment: @Mallesh - I add new version of answer, can you test?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the same column then you can use

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': ['9 years 3 months 22 days',
                           '9 years 3 months 21 days',
                           '9 years 3 months 20 days']})
for idx in range(len(df)):
    if df.time[idx] is np.NaN:
        continue
    # Extract values from string
    val = df.time[idx].lower()
    if ' ' in val:
        val = val.split()
        t = {val[i + 1]: int(val[i]) for i in range(0, len(val), 2)}
        # calculate float value upto two decimal places
        float_val = "{:.2f}".format(t.get("years", 0) + (t.get("months", 0)/12) + (t.get("days", 0)/365))
        # update table
        df.time[idx] = float_val
```

Comment: Some of the column values already converted. at that time the loop is throwing error. In that case what i need to make changes to overcome this issue.

Comment: I did the error handling and updated my answer, if you have any questions then let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the update and will let you know if any error which might occur.